# Why doesn't 'if' statement work? UIView hidden property comparison

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have this if statement here:

```
    if ((_twoStone.hidden == YES) && (_oneStone.hidden == YES)) {
        NSLog(@"Best move count: %.02f", [self starRating]);
    }
```

I can tell the statement when checking the constraints is not working because my output isn't even showing the NSLog.

Is this the right way to code something like that?  By the time the if statement is executed, the UIViews _oneStone and _twoStone hidden properties are both YES (which allows for the NSLog to do its thing).   I also tried

```
    if ((_twoStone.hidden) && (_oneStone.hidden)) {
        // stuff
    }
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `if` statement. Look at the values. Are they what you expect?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this so what values would I be looking at? Rather, what information would I be looking at?

Comment: 1) Make sure neither `_twoStone` or `_oneStone` are `nil`. 2) Then look at the value of `hidden` for each. Are they what you expect?

Comment: So what I have found that I think tells me something is: stayHiddenAwaitingReuse = 0.  Which makes sense because it's not hidden just yet (either _twoStone/_oneStone).  The way I have it set up, I can't get the breakpoint to give me anything useful because of the way I interact with my View.  I swipe the view around this board, and eventually it becomes hidden.  However, the if statement is located in my move method so when I swipe once on my iTouch, the breakpoint is enacted before hidden = YES.  Any suggestions or just keep trying?

Comment: But just to clarify, what I'm analyzing in my if statement is correct, right?  It's not being skipped over because it can't evaluate it correct?

Comment: Due to the weirdness of C your first version of the `if` is technically wrong - never test a boolean for equality with `YES` just test it directly, but will often work, your second version is fine and the `if` will evaluate to true when both `_twoStone.hidden` and `_oneStone.hidden` are true. (If you are curious about the weirdness: booleans have *more than two values*, only one is false, the rest are true, `YES` is just one possible true value.) HTH